# Replacing strings, not characters without the use of .replace and joining the strings the characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Question has been asked that is similar but all post on here refer to replacing single characters. I'm trying to replace a whole word in a string. I've replaced it but I cant print it with spaces in between.

Here is the function `replace` that replaces it:

```
def replace(a, b, c):
    new = b.split()
    result = ''
    for x in new:
        if x == a:
            x = c
        result +=x
    print(' '.join(result))
```

Calling it with:

```
replace('dogs', 'I like dogs', 'kelvin')
```

My result is this:

```
i l i k e k e l v i n
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
I like kelvin
```

Comment: How sensitive do you need to be to spacing, e.g. 2 spaces in the input?

Comment: No idea honestly.

Comment: Do you need to replace substrings too, e.g. `hotdogs -> hotkelvin`?

Comment: Yes I do!! @AChampion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substrings and space preserving method:

```
def replace(a, b, c):
    # Find all indices where 'a' exists
    xs = []
    x = b.find(a)
    while x != -1:
        xs.append(x)
        x = b.find(a, x+len(a))

    # Use slice assignment (starting from the last index)
    result = list(b)
    for i in reversed(xs):
        result[i:i+len(a)] = c

    return ''.join(result)

>>> replace('dogs', 'I like dogs dogsdogs and   hotdogs', 'kelvin')
'I like kelvin kelvinkelvin and   hotkelvin'
```

Comment: What is "i" in your example? i get an error saying its not defined. Sorry to be so bothersome.

Comment: One last question, what does this list comprehension mean? result[i:i+len(a)] = b @AChampion

Comment: It's a slice assignment... not a list comprehension. `x = [1,2,3,4]; x[1:3] = [5, 6, 7]`, `x` now equals `[1, 5, 6, 7, 4]`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `result` is a string and when `join` is called it will take each character in `result` and join it on a space.

Instead, use a `list` , `append` to it (it's also faster than using `+=` on strings) and print it out by unpacking it.

That is:

```
def replace(a, b, c):
    new = b.split(' ')
    result = []
    for x in new:
        if x == a:
            x = c
        result.append(x)
    print(*result)
```

`print(*result)` will supply the elements of the `result` list as positional arguments to print which prints them out with a default white space separation.

`"I like dogs".replace("dogs", "kelvin")` can of course be used here but I'm pretty sure that defeats the point.

Comment: What does the asterisk in your print(*results) do?

Comment: Avoids the call to `' '.join()` by passing all the elements in the list as args to `print`, effectively equivalent to calling: `print(result[0], result[1], result[2], ...)`

Comment: Don't think my example work for multiple instances of the word your looking for either. Any advice on that?

Comment: Calling `replace("dogs", "I like dogs dogs", "kelvin")` returns `"I like kelvin kelvin"` for me @KelvinDavis. It doesn't behave like that for you?

Comment: it does but if i call something like:
("dogs", "cats", "I own 3 dogs and I hate dogs...")
or
wordReplace("test1", "test2", "test1test1test2test1test1 test2test1")
It doesnt work.

Comment: Why would that work @KelvinDavis? You're passing `'cats'` as the `b` argument. Your function needs to be modified to accept more than one arguments for replacement.

Comment: Im sorry, i rearranged the code to accept the arguments in a different order. Thought it would be more clear. now its (word to find, replace with this word, and the sentence your using. Sorry

Comment: I see why it doesnt work its only comparing string to string and not a string to a group of text. dog != ...dog Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `result` a list, and the joining will work:

```
result = []
```

You are just generating one long string and join its chars.